# How to link to other view when use oe_kanban_global_click

Tags: odoo, odoo-10

How to open tree view when click on kanban card when use

> oe_kanban_global_click

It goes to form view but i want on click, goes to tree view. Below code i used:

```
<templates>              
  <t t-name="kanban-box">    
    <div t-attf-class="oe_kanban_color_#{kanban_getcolor(record.color.raw_value)} oe_kanban_card oe_kanban_global_click">
      <div class="o_kanban_record_bottom">
        <div class="oe_kanban_bottom_left">
          <span><strong>Weather:&#160;</strong><t t-esc="record.weather_type.value"/></span>
        </div>
        <div class="oe_kanban_bottom_right">
          <span><strong>Humidity:&#160;</strong><t t-esc="record.humidity.value"/>%</span>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>                
    </t>
</templates>
```

Comment: clicking in the Kanban card is like clicking on the tree view row. if you want so you need to update the default behavior of on click event in the javascript.

Comment: check you linked in message ok

Answer (score 0):

One way to do it it's just to add an anchor tag somewhere and trigger an action.

Here's an example.

On your kanban view put your anchor tag somewhere like this:

```
<strong class="o_kanban_record_title">
    <a name="open_tree_view" title="Placeholder" type="object" context="{'id': id}">
        <field name="name"/>
    </a>
</strong>
```

On your model add the function and return an action:

```
def open_tree_view(self):
    return {
        "type": "ir.actions.act_window",
        "name": "Action name",
        "res_model": "your.model",
        "views": [[False, "tree"]],
        "target": "new",
        "res_id": self.env.context.get("id"),
    }
```